# VB6 How to Suppress Security Message with MAPI Control

Tags: vb6

This is the most common message we face, i have seen the code to resolve this by other means, but don't have an idea how to resolve this by using MAPIMessages Control. Please help

```
"A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in outlook...."
"A program is trying to send an email message on your behalf...."
```

Comment: There is no way around these messages with `MAPIMessages` control. See this for good enough description of the matter: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52

Answer (score 0):

I use Redemption with VB6 to get around this.
http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm